# If $f'(x)=\sin{(x)}$ and $f\left(\pi\right)=3$, then $f(x)=$?

Tags: calculus

If ${\rm f}'\left(x\right) = \sin\left(x\right)$ and ${\rm f}\left(\pi\right) = 3$, then ${\rm f}\left(x\right) =\ ?$.

I understand that the derivative of $-\cos\left(x\right)$ is $\sin\left(x\right)$, but i really don't understand where the $3$ comes from. I have tried everything that comes to mind but I am stuck on this question. If anybody could help that would be awesome.

Thank you!

Comment: The classical error: *missing the $+C$*..

Answer (score 8):

$f'(x) = \sin(x)$ implies that
$$f(x) = -\cos(x) + C$$
where $C\in\mathbb{R}$ ist some constant real number.

With $f(\pi)=3$ now follows
$$3=-cos(\pi) + C = 1 + C \Longleftrightarrow C = 2 $$

Thus
$$f(x) = -\cos(x) +2$$